# How to paraphrase 'to provide an opportunity'

Tags: paraphrasing

The alternative word for 'opportunity' is 'chance' in Oxford Thesaurus; however, 'to provide a chance' does not sound right. How can you paraphrase 'to provide (someone) an opportunity?

'On the one hand, living abroad can provide one better opportunities. For instance, a persevering student who can not access the books and the labs he or she needs at the university or even in the country can find and access the sources he or she needs in another country. '

Comment: Hi! Welcome to ELL! Sorry but we do not help your paraphrase for you without you giving more context, information and evidence that you have put in effort to solve the question. Next time you ask a question, make sure to show your context and research! :3

Comment: @DialFrost Hello! I edited the question, thanks :)

Comment: No, _provide a chance_ doesn't sound right, but _give someone the chance [to do something]_ is perfectly natural.

Answer (score 0):

> How can you paraphrase 'to provide (someone) an opportunity' ?

We might use:

> to ***enable*** someone to do something

See also:

- to empower
- to facilitate
- to set someone up
- to provide the means